# Translation for files in different languages in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, localization, translation, laravel-livewire

I have a multilingual website (English, Azerbaijani, and French) that I am developing with Laravel. I translated its static parts with JSON files (`en.json`, `az.json`, `fr.json`), but how can I access the translation resources (`validation.php`, `auth.php`, `pagination.php`, and `password.php`) of Azerbaijani and French or even any other language?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/localization#retrieving-translation-strings should have the information you're looking for

Comment: @aynber I read Laravel documentation and after that, I asked this question. How can I access the ready-translated files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create its folder in lang directory. for example lang/fr/auth.php and translate it.

You can use this package:
https://github.com/Laravel-Lang/lang